# mongodb query aggregation, checking how many times a key corresponds to a value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

I want to add 2 fields to this MongoDB query.
Field number 1: wins
I want to check all documents and count how many times each person has a value of 1. In other words,
I want to check how many times each person has "won" (gotten 1st place). With this I want the JSON to look like this.

```
[{
"player": "Tormod",
"wins": 2,
"total+/-": 24,
"totalThrows": 148},{
"player": "Andreas",
"total+/-": 34,
"wins": 0,
"totalThrows": 158},{
"player": "Martin",
"wins": 2,
"total+/-": 25,
"totalThrows": 149}]
```

Secondly, I want to give points based on each player's placements. 1st place gives 3 points, 2nd place gives 2 points and 3 place gives 1. If there is a tie between players, for example, first place the points will be given as follows: 3+2/2 = 2,5
With this the final JSON file would look like this:

```
 [{
"player": "Tormod",
"wins": 2,
"points": 7.5,
"total+/-": 24,
"totalThrows": 148},{
"player": "Andreas",
"total+/-": 34,
"points": 3,
"wins": 0,
"totalThrows": 158},{
"player": "Martin",
"points": 7.5,
"total+/-": 25,
"totalThrows": 149}]
```

Is this even possible given the structure of my document?
Under is a link with an example JSON document and where I'm currently at

https://mongoplayground.net/p/Zkkq5EpUBMZ

What I have been trying:

```
_id2: "$placements._id",
  wins: {
    $cond: {
      if: {
        $gte: [
          "$Tormod",
          1
        ]
      },
      then: 3,
      else: 0
    }
  },
```

Comment: i can't see any `wins` or `won` field in your documents, can you explain how to know user won or not?

Comment: A user has won a round if the value in placements is 1. So, in round 2, both "Tormod" and "Martin" got a tie, meaning they shared the 1st place.

Answer (score 0):

I think is better your create a single indice for the wins like

```
[{
        "player": "Tormod",
        "wins1st": 2,
        "wins2st": 1,
        "wins3st": 3,
        "total+/-": 24,
        "totalThrows": 148},{
        "player": "Andreas",
        "total+/-": 34,
```

And when your i gonna save the points you can create a function to sum and save the points in a single indice

When your create a single indice for the wins, you can use the findOne to search the indice and get the value  https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findOne

Comment: This would cause some troubles in case of any ties, wouldnt it? Because you cant see which round it is.